# Value of provider in Persistence.xml

Tags: jpa

What is the value to be set in provider XML element of persistence.xml if the Oracle database is used? Which jars need to included to write a simple JPA application?. 
I have currently included only ejb3-persistence.jar.

When the application is run, below error is seen,
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManage

Answer (score 0):

Decide which JPA implementation you're going to use :- some to choose from [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org), OpenJPA, Hibernate, EclipseLink all of which support persistence to Oracle RDBMS, and there are likely others. Each has a "provider" class name, so you use that in *persistence.xml*